# Google Cloud Load Balancer Reverse DNS Entry

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Anyone know how to change the Reverse DNS entries for the public ip addresses assigned to a google load balancer.

I see you can now do this for GCE instances, but can't see a way for Load Balancers.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, currently this is not possible; however, there is [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/122377974), for this feature to create or change the Reverse DNS(PTR records)entries for the public IP addresses assigned to a google load balance.